# Identifying the index number in a group of counts

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that I need to tally and group by group.
But I also want to identify the index(?) of the observation in the grouping.

The group `A` has `4` observations, I want to to attach an index of `3` for the 3rd `A` observation.

```
df %>% 
group_by(group) %>% 
mutate(count = n())

#   group index count
#1      A    1     4
#2      A    2     4
#3      A    3     4
#4      A    4     4
#5      B    1     1
#6      B    2     1
#7      C    1     3
#8      C    2     3
#9      C    3     3
#10     D    1     1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [window function](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) `row_number()`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) # explicit would be row_number(group)
```